# Как laravel "разбирает" маршруты на составные части?

Tags: php, laravel

Стало любопытно, а каким образом laravel парсит маршруты и понимает какой маршрут сопоставить с правильным url? Например, что url

```
www.ru/post/100/comments/500
```

Должен обработаться соответствующим маршрутом?

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', [NameConroller::class, 'show']);
```

На первый взгляд кажется, что

1. мы должны входящий маршрут разбить(explode например) по /.
2. Потом "найти" все маршруты, в которых первая часть начинается с /post
3. Из найденных на предыдущем пункте маршрутов мы должны понять(не очевидно - как?), что /{post} соответствует любому числу. И т.д.

Возможно, кто-то копался в сорцах или просто знает как оно устроено? Было бы интересно узнать)

Comment: я вот в лараевелом знаком по диагональному чтению документации года назад, и то по моему помню, что {post} соответствует не любому числу  а по типу первичного ключа модели Post. Никто там особо по explode ничего бить не будет, ибо путь может быть и без разделителей. регулярки там будут

Comment: Это было лишь предположение нарочно не правильное, что бы меня поправили)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодится.
Laravel преобразует маршрут в регулярное выражение и ищет по всем имеющимся роутам. Например роут

```
/posts/{post}/comments/{comment}
```

преобразуется в

```
{^/posts/(?P<post>[^/]++)/comments/(?P<comment>[^/]++)$}sDu
```